# Definition: Norm of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

The norm of a finite field extension $L|K $ is defined as $N:L\to K $, $a\mapsto N (a):=\det (m_a) $, where $m_a:L\to L, x\mapsto ax$.

It is easy to show for $a\in L $, that $N (a)=a^{[L:K]} $. Consider the field extension $\Bbb {C}|\Bbb {R} $ and $i \in \Bbb {C} $. By the foregoing section $N (i)=i^2=-1$. Now $B=(1,i)$ is an $\Bbb {R}$-basis of $\Bbb {C} $ and

$$M(m_i)=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & -1 \\
   1 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$$

is the matrix of $m_i $ with respect to $B $. But $N(M(m_i))=\det (M (m_i )) =1\neq -1$.

Why do I get different solutions for my calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a\in K$ you have that $N(a)=a^{[L:K]}$, but it's not generally true for $a\in L$, as your example shows.

The reason it's true for $a\in K$ is that the matrix of $a$ is then just the $[L:K]\times [L:K]$ diagonal matrix with diagonal entries equal to $a$.